# ¿Cómo prohibir un espacio con una expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, typescript

Me gustaría saber cómo prohíbo un espacio con una expresión regular.

He intentado `/\ /` y no funciona.

Comment: No sé qué tiene que ver todo el código que publicaste con lo que estás buscando

Comment: mejor ahora, un saludo y comenta si sabes la respuesta, gracias

Answer (score 2):

> cómo prohíbo un espacio en una expresión regular

No es necesario usar una expresión regular para ver si el texto tiene o no un espacio. En cambio, podrías usar [String#indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf).

```
if (texto.indexOf(' ') > -1) {
    // Código para cuando el valor tiene un espacio y es inválido
}
```

O, sólo para completar la respuesta, para hacerlo con un regex (aunque es totalmente innecesario):

```
if (/ /.test(texto)) {
    // Código para cuando el valor tiene un espacio y es inválido
}
```

---

**Antes de editar la pregunta**

> ¿hay alguna expresión regular que me permita sólo 1 caracter 
>   "-" al principio, otro caracter de ",", solo números y **ningún espacio**?

Expresión regular:

```
/^-?\d+(?:,\d+)?$/
```

Ejemplo:

```js
function validar() {
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  var regex = /^-?\d+(?:,\d+)?$/;
  var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  
  if (regex.test(texto)) {
    resultado.innerText = "Es un número";
  } else {
    resultado.innerText = "No válido";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" style="width: 100%">
<input type="button" value="Validar" onclick="validar()">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

Comment: el index of funciona genial, en cuanto a la expresión regular la usaré en un replace a ver si consigo el resultado que quiero, muchas gracias por tu ayuda Mariano

Comment: @JulioAguilar Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió usando el check que está debajo de los botones de votación de la respuesta.